# Form inputs in bootstrap 3 modals not rendering changes or content in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a rails app in which I'm displaying some forms in bootstrap 3 modals. In chrome (I don't see this bug in firefox) when I type in one of the text fields, or select something from a select list, the fields remain blank. If there's some change to the page, like a resizing, or zooming in, etc, the added values appear.

I'm having trouble identifying the issue. If I remove the bootstrap css, the form fields work fine. I at first though the issue was the :focus styles, but removing those did not fix the issue. Is anyone else seeing this problem? It only occurs in the modal forms. Below is the relevant code...

Sample Form partial

```
<div id="modal-form" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="fa fa-file"></span> Attach file</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
            <br>
            <fieldset>
              <%= render 'layouts/direct_upload_form' %>
              <p class="box-instructions">Maximum file size is 5GB.</p>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>

        <%= form_for([@attachable, @file_attachment], html:{class:'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :s3_key, :value => (params[:file_attachment][:s3_key] if params[:file_attachment].present?) %>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :subject, class:'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <%= select_tag :subject_select, options_for_select([[''], ['Agreement'], ['Background'], ['Deliverables'], ['Finished sample'], ['Image'], ['Script'], ['Special effects'], ['Other']]), class:'form-control' %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-2">
            <%= f.text_field :subject, class:'form-control hide subject-field' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :description, class:'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <%= f.text_area :description, rows:4, class:'form-control' %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-right">
          <%= f.submit "Save", class:'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <% end %>
      </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

EDIT

It seems as though this bit of code is causing issues with the input fields in modals -

```
var CanvasImage=function(e,t)
{
    this.image=t,
    this.element=e,
    this.element.width=this.image.width,
    this.element.height=this.image.height;
    var n=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome")>-1,
    r=navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")>-1;
    n&&r&&(this.element.width=Math.min(this.element.width,1200),this.element.height=Math.min(this.element.height,2000)),
    this.context=this.element.getContext("2d"),
    this.context.drawImage(this.image,0,0)
};
CanvasImage.prototype={
    blur:function(e){
        this.context.globalAlpha=.5;
        for(var t=-e;t<=e;t+=2)
            for(var n=-e;n<=e;n+=2)
                this.context.drawImage(this.element,n,t),
            n>=0&&t>=0&&this.context.drawImage(this.element,-(n-1),-(t-1));
            this.context.globalAlpha=1
        }
},

CanvasImage.prototype={
    blur:function(e){
        this.context.globalAlpha=.5;
        for(var t=-e;t<=e;t+=2)
            for(var n=-e;n<=e;n+=2)
                this.context.drawImage(this.element,n,t),
            n>=0&&t>=0&&this.context.drawImage(this.element,-(n-1),-(t-1));
            this.context.globalAlpha=1
        }
},

$(function(){
    var image,canvasImage,canvas;
    $(".blur").each(function(){
        canvas=this,
        image=new Image,
        image.onload=function(){
            canvasImage=new CanvasImage(canvas,this),
            canvasImage.blur(4)
        },
        image.src=$(this).attr("src");
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post a bootply or a jsfiddle ? for us to test your code.

Comment: For the life of me I can't replicate the error on bootply. But, in the process I identified a piece of js that creates the bug when present. It's a couple functions for blurring a backgorund image. Here's a bootply of the desired behavior - http://www.bootply.com/uSB5yaIqIq I'll add the blur function to the question.